# Geometric representation of $\int_a^b r(\theta )\, d\theta$ in polar coordinates?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, geometry, definite-integrals, polar-coordinates

In polar coordinates with $r$ as radius and $\theta$ as azimuth, the arc length between the points corresponding to $\theta =a$ and $\theta =b$ is given by
$$\int_a^b \sqrt{r^2(\theta )+r'^2(\theta )}\, d\theta.$$
if $0\lt b-a\lt 2\pi$.

On the other hand, the area enclosed by $r(\theta )$ and the rays $\theta =a$ and $\theta =b$ is
$$\frac{1}{2}\int_a^b r^2(\theta )\, d\theta$$
if $0\lt b-a\le 2\pi$.

In Cartesian coordinates $(x,y)$,
$$\int_a^b y(x)\, dx$$
represents the familiar area under a curve from $x=a$ to $x=b$.

But what is the geometric representation of
$$\int_a^b r(\theta )\, d\theta$$
in polar coordinates?

Comment: Nothing useful, I'm afraid.

Comment: There are "tautological" answers, such as "the area of the preimage in the $(r, \theta)$ plane of the region inside the polar graph" or "twice the area enclosed by the polar graph of $\sqrt{r(\theta)}$", but that's probably not what you're seeking.